# PDO showing more results than expected

Tags: php, pdo

I have a simple table with one field "id", and when I execute this code...

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM logolist';
$q = $dbh->query($sql);
while($r = $q->fetch()){ print_r($r); }
```

... I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [0] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 4
    [0] => 4
)
```

As you see, there's a [0] under the field "ID". if I add more field, I keep getting more extra elements inside the array. It's like every field is outputting it's value 2 times.

Why is this?

Comment: did you try with `while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ print_r($r); }`?

Comment: Why are people using a while loop to fetch PDO results?

Comment: When you work with `mysql_*` for about 10 years you have a small paranoia and tend to do same stupid things over and over. I believe you got my point @N.B. :)

Comment: I do get your point, been there, done that, found a better way and hopefully I'll start seeing more people using it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm encountering this practice of having a loop for fetching MySQL results and I'm wondering why people do it so I'll write up this answer and try to clear up a few things.

1) You do not need a loop to fetch results 
2) Reason you get the results duplicated is because you're receiving an associative array and index-based one. That's the default behaviour.

What you can do is this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

// Tell PDO to throw exceptions in case of a query error
$dbh ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try
{
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM logolist")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    // Your result is now in $result array which is associative. 
    // If it's empty - no results were found. 
    // In case of an error, you'd go to catch block of the code and you'd echo out an error. 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error reported: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This approach is not recommended. If you wanted to use the PDOStatement object, you wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you're off here. If you have any sources that claim that this approach isn't recommended - please post them to support your claims and please show how you would be unable to use PDOStatement in this particular case.

Comment: How can you? Like you said, `$result` is now an array. You can do nothing with the original `PDOStatement` object, as the reference to it is lost. Also, there's a very VERY wide debate over method chaining in PHP and in general, strongest arguments against, it hinders readability, and makes it difficult to understand what the final result it. In this case, the valuable `PDOStatement` object, is lost as well. If you wanted to, lets say, execute the query again, you wouldn't be able to do so (without creating another query, and another instance).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha But.. certain queries are not exactly queries that you want to execute again.. like, `SELECT * FROM logolist`.  It seems like a very, 'this is the one time I'm going to query for all of this data for this page'.

I feel most `select` queries actually warrant a fetchAll and simply getting the entire array, as opposed to what I feel is the old fashioned and ugly practice of `$row = fetch();`.. and `$row` really should be named `$logos` in this case.  I mean, this code clearly wants a bunch of associative arrays.

Comment: @Anther: That's not always the case, what if I wanted to process every row in a table and execute an update query based on the results of that processing? `$stmt->fetch()` would then make perfect sense. That's why I said it's a generally not recommended approach.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - what's the point in presenting a doomsday scenario which no one ever encounters? If you need to repeat "SELECT *" query multiple times, you're doing something very wrong. As I don't want to go into debate about losing a `PDOStatement` object that wasn't present, I'll just try to clarify why I posted this - **so I can show that the OP doesn't have to use a while loop to fetch data from the query**. Everything you said so far, especially about method chaining, wasn't backed up so we haven't got anything to talk about. Thanks for reading.

Comment: @N.B.: I never said not to use `fetchAll()`, I use it all the time, it's perfectly acceptable. I just don't chain methods that way, so you skip over object references. `$stmt = $pdo->query(); $result = $stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: You were talking about method chaining and losing object reference. First off, if you need to repeat a query multiple times - you won't do it the way I depicted. My example is only to show how you can fetch data without using a loop. Since there was a simple query involved that didn't require parameters of any kind, I just made it a one-liner. That's all. As for "standards" - we can debate about that at another place.

Comment: All answers were a great help. I accepted this one because it taught me also a different way to fetch information without looping which I found interesting for my case. That's all. Thanks for your discussion anyway. I'll take in account all your comments.

Answer (score 4):

That is normal for `fetch()` without any attribute (it's sets `FETCH_BOTH` by default). It works like old `mysql_fetch_array()` and `0` is the numerical index.

If you switch to Associative you will get only fields:

```
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($r);
}
```

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) - for all styles.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching both numerical and associative.

Check the PDO documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

(You are using PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default))

Comment: Read the page. It has examples.

Comment: http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/210/119/+_2acc5a8841f8752904d37f90a8014829.png, It should appear in your answer. People accessing this page from Google don't want to click through 3 different websites to get an answer, also, providing full answers would grant you more votes.

Answer (score 1):

```
  while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ print_r($r); }
```

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will only get values with their associative keys, without numerical indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` gives numerical and associative array

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

you can use `FETCH_ASSOC` for only getting associative array